# Changing the RSS feed titles not working

Tags: custom-post-types, rss, feed

I'm trying to change my RSS feed titles to display the post type beforehand but it's not working.

Code below. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
function changeRSStitles($content) {

global $post;

if (get_post_type($post) == 'literature') {
    $content = 'Literature: '.$content;
} else if (get_post_type($post) == 'recipe') {
    $content = 'Recipe: '.$content;
} else if (get_post_type($post) == 'restaurant') {
    $content = 'Restaurant: '.$content;
} else if (get_post_type($post) == 'post') {
    $content = 'Sugar Street Blog: '.$content;
}else {
    $content = $content;
}

return $content;
}

add_filter('the_title_rss', 'changeRSStitles');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it working! Just had to resync the feedburner feed